# Filtro de Búsqueda con varios campos, con opción a estar vacíos, MySQli

Tags: php, mysqli

Quisiera implementar un sistema de busquedad, donde se puedan llenar varios campos, pero con la opcion de que pueden estar algunos vacios.

Como seria la codificacion del php?

HTML:

PHP

```
$dato1=$_POST["dato1"];
$dato2=$_POST["dato2"];
$dato3=$_POST["dato3"];
$dato4=$_POST["dato4"];

    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE dato1='$dato1' && dato2='$dato2' && dato3='$dato4' && dato4='$dato4'"); 
       $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$dato1,$dato2,$dato3,$dato4);
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->store_result();
       $stmt->bind_result($resultadodelsql);
       $stmt->fetch();
       echo $stmt;
       $stmt->close();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Busque una respuesta a esta pregunta en stackoverflow.com

sacado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206530/search-filtering-with-php-mysql

encontre una forma de hacer el filtro de busqueda y lo adapte a $statement mysqli, quedando algo asi

**Filtro de Busqueda Dinamico:**

```
        <?php

       $numero=$_POST["numero"];
       $cedula1=$_POST["cedula1"];
       $cedula2=$_POST["cedula2"]; 
       $fechaini=$_POST["fecha_ini"]; 
       $fechater=$_POST["fecha_ter"]; 

/*FILTRO DE BUSQUEDA DINAMICO: Este sistema buscara los campos que se hallan llenado en la consulta, agregandolos a la sentencia SQL, el truco de esto es ir CONCATENANDO todo lo que deseemos que se busque o guarde*/

/*Primer Paso: Creo una variable que guardara la sentencia base, en este caso para seleccionar en sanciones*/

$query = "SELECT * FROM sanciones";


/*Segundo Paso: Creo una string vacia para que en ella se vayan insertando todos los identificadores seleccionados*/

$identificador = "";

/*Tercer Paso: Creo una string vacia para que en ella se vayan insertando todos los valores que fueron POSTeados, es decir, cedula, nombre, medida, etc*/

$valor = "";


/*Cuarto Paso: tres arreglos ¡por que? porque lo que hara este sistema sera ir concatenando las opciones que sean llenadas tanto para los identificadores como para las condciiones y valores*/

/*NOTESE: las string son palabras en SINGULAR, los arrays en PLURAL*/
    $condiciones = array();
    $identificadores= array();
    $valores= array();

/*Quinto Paso: Comparo cada valor POSTeado, si no esta vacio guardo los datos correspondientes en los arreglos, condicion para la sentencia sql, tipo de identificador y el valor, esto para cada valor que quiera POSTear*/

    if($numero !="") { 
      $condiciones[] = "id=?"; 
      $identificadores[]="i"; 
      $valores[]= "$numero"; 
    }

    if($cedula1 !="") {
      $condiciones[] = "cedula1=?";
      $identificadores[]="i";
      $valores[]= "$cedula1";
    }

    if($cedula2 !="") {
      $condiciones[] = "cedula2=?";
      $identificadores[]="i";
      $valores[]= "$cedula2";
    }

    if($fechaini !="") {
      $condiciones[] = "fecha_ini=?";
      $identificadores[]="s";
      $valores[]= "$fechaini";
    }

    if($fechater !="") {
      $condiciones[] = "fecha_ter=?";
      $identificadores[]="s";
      $valores[]= "$fechater";
    }

/*Sexto Paso: COMPLETANDO EL STRING DE LA SQL, una vez halla revisao todo asigno el valor de la query inicial a una nueva variable de manera que a esta se le concatene todo el texto de las opciones marcadas*/

    $query_final = $query;

/*Septimo Paso: Cuento los valores que hay en condiciones[] y si fueron mayores de 0 a ese valor $query_final le hare un implode para agregar los valores del array $condiciones*/

    if (count($condiciones) > 0) {
      $query_final .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $condiciones);
    }

/*NOTESE: Aqui ya tenemos una sentencia llena, si se marca todos los valores tenemos algo asi:
SELECT * FROM sanciones WHERE id=? AND cedula1=? AND cedula2=? AND fecha_ini=? AND fecha_ter=?*/


/*Octavo Paso: COMPLETANDO EL STRING DE LOS IDENTIFICADORES, una vez halla revisao todo asigno el valor de la string $identificador inicial a una nueva variable de manera que a esta se le concatene todo el texto de las opciones marcadas*/

    $identificadores_final= $identificador;

/* Cuento los valores que hay en identificadores[] y si fueron mayores de 0 a ese valor $identificador_final le hare un implode para agregar los valores del array, en este caso todas las identificadores*/

    if (count($identificadores) > 0) {
      $identificadores_final .= implode("",$identificadores);
    }

/*Marcando todos los valores quedaria algo asi: iiissii */


/*Noveno Paso: COMPLETANDO EL ARRAY DE LOS VALORES, una vez halla revisado todo asigno el valor de la string $valores inicial a una nueva variable de manera que a esta se le concatene todos los valores de las opciones marcadas*/

/* Para terminar asigno el valor de la string inicial de los valores a una nueva variable*/

    $valores_final= $valor;

/* Cuento los valores que hay en $valores y si fueron mayores de 0 a ese valor $valores_final le hare un implode para agregar los valores del array, en este caso todas los valores*/

    if (count($valores) > 0) {
      $valores_final .= implode(',', $valores);
    }

/* Podria quedar algo asi:
1,25171681,25171681,25171681,2017-1-1,2017-1-2,1
*/

/*NOTESE: En el resto del sistema usabamos BIND_PARAM para asignar los valores y los identificadores a nuestra sentencia preparada $stmt, en este caso hemos visto que tenemos un string con los identificadores (bien) pero un array de valores 
(mal), porque mal?. resulta que bind_param solo acepta dos valores que no sean array: 

bind_param(string, variablesN)

Por eso usaremos otra funcion que ejecuta funciones y permite que le pasemos valores del tipo ARRAY

LA FUNCIONA SE LLAMA "CALL_USER_FUNC_ARRAY" y tiene el siguiente formato:

call_user_func_array ( VALOR1[array('funcion que se quiere llamar',$parametros)] , VALOR2[array($otrosparametros)] )

esta permitira que usemos la funcion BIND_PARAM con arrays

Pero ocurre tambien que bind_param usa la sentencia $stmt, es decir algo asi: $stmt->bind_param, esto hace necesario que se le pase otro valor mas a la funcion CALL_USER_FUNC_ARRAY

Por lo tanto nuestra estructura de la funcion usara 2 array, uno para guardar $stmt y la funcion a ejecutar= "bind_param"
y otro para meter $identificadores y $variables

aprovechamos la funcion y termina quedando algo asi.

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array($identificadores_final), $valores));

Ahora veamos las condiciones de call_user_func_array.

1- se usen arrays
2- sean arrays referenciados

Esto quiere decir que esta funcion no trabajara directamente con $identificaores y $valores, esto daria error, antes es necesario REFERENCIAR dichas variables.

Referenciar(&): es que otra variable "A" tendra el valor de una variable "B" y cuanto esta variable "B" cambie, la variable "A" tambien cambiara, pero los cambios en variable "A" no afectaran a variable "B".

Ejemplo

$a=1
$b=1

$b=$b+2 --> b quedaria en 3

$a=&$b --> a quedaria en 3

$b=$b+3 --> b quedaria en 6

echo $a --> mostraria 9

Call_user_func_array llevaria escrito $identificadores_final e $variables pero usaria su valor referenciado, es decir le ingresamos $b pero usa $a

En el caso de no referenciarlos saldria este error:

Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference --> Se espera que los valores sean referencias

*/

/*Decimo Paso: Creamos la referencia para $valores */

$n=count($valores); //Cuento los valores


for ($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) //Preparo un for que los recorra
{
  $valores_ref[$i]=&$valores[$i]; //Creo $valores_ref como otro array y le asigno de manera referenciada los valores del array $valores
}

/* Hecho esto ya podremos pasar este array con la funcion call_user_func_array, debido a que ya esta referenciado*/


/*Decimo Primer Paso: Preparo la sentencia */

$stmt = $conexion->prepare($query_final);

/*NOTESE: hasta ahora todo deberia marchar bien, tenemos los arrays referenciados y el string con los identificadores, pero ocurre que tenemos tambien el BIND_PARAM , contando tendriamos 3 cosas metidas en la funcion

call_user_func_array ($conexion, $identificadores, $valores)

y este solo permite 2 arrays.

que hacemos? --> Procedemos a unir el array de $identificadores y de $valores.

eso lo hacemos con ARRAY_MERGE, esta funcion permite insertar valores dentro de un array.
*/

/*Decimo Tercer Paso
ejemplo, tenemos esto en nuestras variables:

$identificadores_final            / $valores
array(0)=string i                 array(0)=$numero=24
array(1)=string i                 array(1)=$cedula1=25171681

al aplicar array_merge quedaria

array(0)=i,24
array(1)=i,25171681 

Conviertiendolo en una sola variable

Es decir hacemos esto:

array_merge(array($identificadores_final), $valores)

pasando algo asi:
call_user_func_array(valor1, valor2);*/

/*Decimo Cuarto Paso: Ejecutamos la funcion*/
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array($identificadores_final), $valores));

/*Decimo Quinto PASo: ejecutamos la sentencia*/
    $stmt->execute();
/* Obtenemos los resultados*/
    $resultados=$stmt->get_result();
           while ($datos= $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo $datos["id"]."<br>";
           }
    $stmt->close();

?>
```

Filtro de busqueda Dinamico, 100% funcional..

Tuve que usar call_user_func_Array para pasarle el array de los valores a bind_param, pero antes creando valores referenciados de $variable

Answer (score 2):

Esta es una de las cosas, entre muchas otras, por las que prefiero [PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) a MySQLi.

Estuve mirando la posibilidad de hacer lo que quieres usando MySQLi, pero no lo encontré.

Usando PDO puedes hacerlo creando un arreglo `$arr[]` al cual se irá agregando una condición `AND` si alguno de los campos del `_$POST` contienen datos. Al mismo tiempo se concatenará una nueva condición a la cadena `$sql`. 
Para el dato1, por ejemplo:

```
if($dato1!=""){
    $sql .= " and dato1 = :dato1";
    $arr[] = ":dato1 => $dato1";
}
```

En este caso, PDO evaluará si la columna de la tabla llamada `dato1` es igual al valor pasado como incógnita a través de `:dato1` , es decir, si es igual al valor de la variable `$dato1`.

**Ejemplo completo:**

```
$arr = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE 1";

/*
  * Nota: Aquí podemos también tener una variable
  * booleana establecida en `false`
  * la cual es establecida a `true`
  * cuando se cumplan cualesquiera
  * de las condiciones del if
  * al final enviamos la consulta solo 
  * si la variable es `true`
  * Esto es útil si queremos que la consulta 
  * se envié sí y solo sí se cumple alguna de las condiciones :)
   *
   */

$dato1 = $_REQUEST['dato1'];
if($dato1!=""){
    $sql .= " and dato1 = :dato1";
    $arr[] = ":dato1 => $dato1";
}

$dato2 = $_REQUEST['dato2'];
if($dato2!=""){
    $sql .= " and dato2 = :dato2";
    $arr[] = ":dato2 => $dato2";
}

$dato3 = $_REQUEST['dato3'];
if($dato3!=""){
    $sql .= " and dato3 = :dato3";
    $arr[] = ":dato3 => $dato3";
}

//Construidos nuestros WHERE dinámicos, mandamos la consulta a PDO.

$db = new PDO(DSN, user, password);//conexión sería tu PDO. Es mejor tener una clase dedicada a la conexion 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); //$sql que se ha ido concatenando
$stmt->execute($arr); //PDO permite pasar en parámetro el arreglo completo, él hace el binding de cada variable
$datos = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //arreglo asociativo con los datos. Existen otras formas de obtenerlos, según la necesidad

//Cerrar la conexión si es necesario
```

PD: En otra respuesta ofrecí una clase de conexión PDO completa. Si te interesa puedo actualizar la pregunta compartiendo dicha Clase.

#### Actualización

He creado una clase para manejar no sólo la conexión PDO sino también las consultas enviadas a la misma y las respuestas.

La clase se puede adaptar a las necesidades de cada uno. Dejo a continuación el enlace. En la página de Github explico los pasos para poder usar dicha clase.

> [Clase para conexión PDO, envío de consultas preparadas y manejo de
>   resultados](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO). Se ruega leer bien las instrucciones en Github para
>   que la clase funcione.

**Resolviendo el problema planteado en la pregunta usando la clase:**

```
//Usaremos las variables $sql y $arr construidas como se ha explicado más arriba 
//Tres líneas de código bastarán para hacer el trabajo :) de una forma limpia y entendible 

require_once("DbPDO.class.php");    
$mipdo=new DbPDO();
$datos=$mipdo->query( $sql, $arr );

//Tendrás tus resultados en $datos y podrás leerlo como de costumbre.
```

Comment: si quieres agrega la clase, la cosa seria que tengo clase de conexion y todas las sentencias con mysqli, no hay una forma de adaptar eso?

Comment: obte por mysqli porque probe alrededor de unas 15 clases de pdo y todas daban error, incluso probe como 6 mysqli y ninguna servia, hasta que encontre la que tengo

Comment: +1 por la sugerencia de PDO. Yo hago lo mismo cuando inserto campos opcionales

Comment: @Victor A. Estoy ocupado cuando pueda la comparto. Me funciona muy bien y cuando tienes tu clase funcionando es una maravilla.

Comment: lo esperare jejeje

Comment: @A.Cedano mire bien tu perfil y eres.... SACERDOTE :O que GEENNIIAALLL yo pertenezco al movimiento juvenil salesiano :), ya llevo 4 años en el :) soy asesor

Comment: @VictorA. ¡Qué bueno! Como prometido, he añadido un enlace al final con los archivos de la Clase PDO, que se encuentran en Github.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Prepara el `"WHERE" (if isset... )` del sql fuera de la consulta y luego la introduces como una nueva variable.

Comment: el problema esta en que las sentencias preparadas trabajan asi:

parte solida y dinamica (asi las llamo no recuerdo el nombre) la solida seria el tipo de valor y la dinamica, las variables y debes establecer en el bind_param los valores tanto solidos como dinamicos, porque ya sera un objeto y no un simple string en sql